# Effects of Elementary Row Operations on Invertibility

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose you have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m x m}$ and $\tilde{A}$ is obtained from $A$ by permuting the rows. Does the fact that $A$ is singular/invertible *always* imply that $\tilde{A}$ is singular/invertible, respectively?

My intuition says yes, since $A$ and $\tilde{A}$ necessarily share the same row-space, but I would love a formal proof of this.

Thank you!!

Comment: Your intuition is correct. If $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ is invertible, what must its row space equal?

Comment: The row-space would be equal to the column space, meaning they also share the same column space, meaning they both must be invertible. Makes sense!

Comment: @MatthewPilling if you put this down as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Another way of seeing it is to note that all elementary row operations amount to multiplying the original matrix by another matrix (the result of applying the same elementary row operation on the identity matrix). The multiplying matrix for each row operation is easily seen to be invertible. And the product of two invertible matrices is also invertible.